# Python, dictionary to table and output to csv file

Tags: python, csv

I am programming in python

I have the list as follows:

```
{'Net_rec': [403548, 403548, 403548], 'time': [1, 2, 3], 'disk_write': [219L, 219L, 219L], 'disk_read': [32904L, 32904L, 32904L], 'memory': [104468, 104468, 104468], 'cpu': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 'Net_sent': [36384, 36384, 36384]}
```

And I need to output this list to a csv file and get the list as the table below:

```
time   cpu   memory  disk_read   disk_write   net_send   net_recv
```

and the data below each column name.

How can i do it?

Comment: it is a dict not a list.

Comment: And what have to tried so far?

Comment: What part are you having trouble with? Stack Overflow isn't a "write my code for me" site

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by others in the comments, the data you have is a `dict` and not a `list`. You can transform the data to build a list of lists such that each sub-list has the key and values.

i.e.:

```
[
    ['Net_rec', 403548, 403548, 403548], 
    ['time', 1, 2, 3], 
    ['disk_write', 219L, 219L, 219L], 
    ['disk_read', 32904L, 32904L, 32904L], 
    ['memory', 104468, 104468, 104468], 
    ['cpu', 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
    ['Net_sent', 36384, 36384, 36384]
]
```

and then using [`izip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) will give you what you want.

Code (assuming `data` has your input dict :

```
from itertools import izip

transformed_data = []
for k, v in data.items():
    new_list = [k]
    new_list.extend(v)
    transformed_data.append(new_list)

print list(izip(*transformed_data)
```

This gives:

```
[
    ('Net_rec', 'time', 'disk_write', 'disk_read', 'memory', 'cpu', 'Net_sent'), 
    (403548, 1, 219L, 32904L, 104468, 0.0, 36384), 
    (403548, 2, 219L, 32904L, 104468, 0.0, 36384), 
    (403548, 3, 219L, 32904L, 104468, 0.0, 36384)
]
```

Explore [`writerow`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow) method of csv module to write out the above output into a csv file.